# SQL Server Smaller Date Range Freezes Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

So we have a SQL Server statement to select sales for a specific merchant during a given period.  This works fine for any larger date ranges, whole months, multiple months, or even short periods like weeks or days from February or earlier.

Then when we want to query a small date range, like a few days in May given in the example, the server utilization goes to 100% and just freezes everything up.  This happens for any small date range in the months of March, April, and May, but not before that.

Could it have to do with indexing possibly since these are more recent entries?

```
SELECT 
  CAST(tx.tx_sales_amount AS money) AS tx_sales_amount, 
  tx.LID AS loc_id, 
  tx.tx_date, 
  tx.tx_type, 
  tx.tx_clerk_number, 
  ISNULL(
    LTRIM(
      RTRIM(tx.tx_checknum)
    ), 
    'n/a'
  ) AS tx_checknum, 
  tx.card_number, 
  tx_item, 
  tx.member_id, 
  gp.gift_prg_name, 
  gpl.gift_pid, 
  l.location_name AS location 
FROM 
  tblTransactions tx 
  INNER JOIN tblLocations l ON tx.MID = l.MID 
  AND tx.LID = l.LID 
  INNER JOIN tblTerminals t ON tx.MID = t.MID 
  AND tx.LID = t.LID 
  AND tx.TID = t.TID 
  INNER JOIN tblGift_Program_Lookup gpl ON t.id_pk = gpl.TID_fk 
  INNER JOIN tblPrograms_Gift gp ON gp.gift_pid = gpl.gift_pid 
  INNER JOIN tblCards c ON tx.card_number = c.card_number 
  AND c.card_gift_pid = gp.gift_pid 
WHERE 
  tx.tx_type IN ('10', '50') 
  AND tx.MID = '0199' 
  AND tx.tx_void = 0 
  AND l.location_active = 1 
  AND LEFT(tx.card_number, 4) IN (
    SELECT 
      card_prefix 
    FROM 
      tblCard_Types 
    WHERE 
      card_type IN ('Gift', 'Multi')
  ) 
  AND tx.tx_date BETWEEN '2014-05-01 22:00:00' 
  AND '2014-05-07 20:59:59' 
ORDER BY 
  l.location_name, 
  tx.tx_type, 
  gpl.gift_pid, 
  LEFT(c.card_number, 6), 
  tx.tx_date DESC, 
  tx_clerk_number
```

Comment: I for one would have to do some detailed analysis of the data being queried in order to answer this.

Comment: What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Quite possibly you need to update statistics. This is known as the ascending key problem and is mitigated in SQL Server 2014.